# Perl regex: count leading substrings

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a Perl regex that can count how often a substring occurs at the beginning of another string?

For instance

```
my $string = "../../../../../../../../../Downloads/../Testing/../";

my $countstr = "../";
```

The result should be 9, because there are nine occurrences of `../` at the start of `$string`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a global regular expression and the `\G` anchor, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string   = '../../../../../../../../../Downloads/../Testing/../';
my $countstr = '../';

my $n = () = $string =~ /\G\Q$countstr/g;

print $n, "\n";
```

**output**

```
9
```

Comment: Additionally, if you are trying to match the periods literally (which is how I interpreted the OP's question), and not using them as wildcard characters, then you should quote them like this: `my $n = () = $string =~ /\G\Q$countstr\E/g;`